# ListBoxFor(Lambda Expression) not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Getting the following errors for the code snippet below: Cannot resolve method with ListBoxFor(Lambda Expression) and cannot convert Lambda expression to type 'string'

```
  <form>
     <div class="form-group">


    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ComplaintRcvdBy)
    @Html.TextBox(m => m.ComplaintRcvdBy, new {@class = "form-control"})
</div>
```

Comment: You might be missing `System.Linq`  * `System.Data.Entity` name space.

Comment: [Html.ListBoxFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.listboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx) take two arguments min

Comment: @Venky but I can able to add System.Link onto a .cshtml layout

Comment: `@using System.Linq`

Comment: Usually all these namespaces should be defined in web.config file to be able to access across all the files in the project.   `<system.web.webPages.razor> ...... </system.web.webPages.razor>`

Comment: I think it's not the problem @Venky. ListBoxFor with lambda take 2 arguments...

Comment: Yea. That could also be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Html.ListBoxFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.listboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx) with lambda take two arguments

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ComplaintRcvdBy, /** IEnumerable<SelectListItem> **/)
```

I think you want to use `LabelFor` no ?

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ComplaintRcvdBy)
        @Html.TextBox(m => m.ComplaintRcvdBy, new {@class = "form-control"})
    </div>
</form>
```